# How to calculate the covariance of the empirical distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, covariance, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X_i$ be iid random variables with distribution function $F(x)$. How to calculate $\textbf{Cov}[F_n(x),F_m(y)]$ where $F_n(x)$ is the empirical cumulative distribution function and $n,m\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: What are $x,\,y,\,F_n$ in terms of $X_i,\,F$?

Comment: x,y are points in $\mathbb R$, $F_n(x)=F_n(x,\omega)$ is the ecdf of $X_i$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: But covariances have to be of nondegenerate random variables.

Comment: They are not degenerate. We know that $nF_n(x)\sim Be(n,F(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [F_n(X)] &= \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^nF_k(x)\\
\end{align*}
and similarly
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [F_m(X)] &= \frac{1}{m} \sum\limits_{k=1}^mF_k(x)
\end{align*}
Now we calculate $\mathbb E [F_n(X)F_m(X)]$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [F_n(X)F_m(X)] &= \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{l=1}^m\mathbb E \left[\tt1[X_k\leq x]\tt1[X_l\leq x]\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{nm}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{l=1}^m\mathbb P[X_k\leq x \wedge X_l\leq x]\\
&= \frac{1}{nm}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\bigg[\sum\limits_{l=1}^{k-1}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x \wedge X_l\leq x]+\\
&\qquad\sum\limits_{l=k}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x \wedge X_l\leq x]+
\sum\limits_{l=k+1}^{m}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x \wedge X_l\leq x]\bigg]\\
&= \frac{1}{nm}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\bigg[\sum\limits_{l=1}^{k-1}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x]\mathbb P[X_l\leq x]+\\
&\qquad\mathbb P[X_k\leq x]+
\sum\limits_{l=k+1}^{m}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x]\mathbb P[X_l\leq x]\bigg]\\
&= \frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x] + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{l\in [m]\setminus\{k\}}\mathbb P[X_k\leq x]\mathbb P[X_l\leq x]\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}F_{k}(x) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{l\in [m]\setminus\{k\}}F_{k}(x)F_{l}(x)\right]\\
\end{align*}

We use independence in the 4th equality. Note that we have not used identically distributed so far.

Now we can calculate the covariance.
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Cov}[F_n(x),F_m(y)]&=\mathbb E [F_n(X)F_m(X)] - \mathbb E [F_n(X)]\times\mathbb E [F_m(X)]\\
&=\frac{1}{nm}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{l=1}^m\mathbb P[X_k\leq x \wedge X_l\leq x] - \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^nF_k(x)\times\frac{1}{m} \sum\limits_{l=1}^mF_l(x)\\
&=\frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}F_{k}(x) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{l\in [m]\setminus\{k\}}F_{k}(x)F_{l}(x) -  
\sum\limits_{k=1}^nF_k(x)\times\sum\limits_{l=1}^mF_l(x)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}F_{k}(x) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^nF_{k}(x)\sum\limits_{l\in [m]\setminus\{k\}}F_{l}(x) -  
\sum\limits_{k=1}^nF_k(x)\times\sum\limits_{l=1}^mF_l(x)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}F_{k}(x) -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}[F_{k}(x)]^2 \right]\\
\end{align*}
where the last step is due to the rest of the terms cancelling. Using identically distributed property now:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Cov}[F_n(x),F_m(y)]&=\frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}F_{k}(x) -[F_{k}(x)]^2 \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{nm}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{min(n,m)}F_{X}(x) -[F_{X}(x)]^2 \right]\\
&=\frac{{min(n,m)}}{nm}\left[F_{X}(x)(1 -F_{X}(x)) \right]\\
\end{align*}

Therefore: $\textbf{Cov}[F_n(x),F_m(y)]=\frac{{min(n,m)}}{nm}\left[F_{X}(x)(1 -F_{X}(x)) \right]$

Comment: There is nothing in the question that asks to find $E [F_n(X)]$. More importantly, please avoid giving such detailed responses to questions having no personal input. This is all the OP was hoping for and you didn't disappoint him/her.

Comment: $cov(F_n(x),F_m(x))  = \mathbb E(F_n(x)\times F_m(x)) - \mathbb E(F_n(x)) \mathbb E(F_m(x))$, so i do need $\mathbb E(F_n(x))$. As regards efforts, point noted.

Comment: You do need $E(F_n(x))$ but it is nowhere in your answer.  OP doesn't complain though.